# HTTPS-friendly jQuery CSS theme from Google CDN

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, https, google-cdn

Just trying to get an https friendly version of google's hosted jquery css themes, i.e

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

loading 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css works, except then there are problems that some of the icons themselves are not served from https. namely:

> The page at https://mysite.com ran insecure content from
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css.
>   The page at https://mysite.com/ displayed insecure content
>   from
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png.
>   The page at https://mysite.com/ displayed insecure content
>   from
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png.
>   The page at https://mysite.com/ displayed insecure content
>   from
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png.
>   The page at https://mysite.com/ displayed insecure content
>   from
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png.
>   The page at https://mysite.com/ displayed insecure content
>   from
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png.

I want it hosted from google.

Comment: Don't use all-caps in your titles.

Answer (score -1):

You *cannot* do anything about it. Because `jquery-ui.css` from  `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css` internally uses *images* with `http://...` only.

Try [protocol-relative URL](http://www.google.com/search?q=protocol%20relative%20URL) (by [section 4.2 of RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2)):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"  
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: -1 Take a look at the code next time.  ALL images loaded from the link you provided are RELATIVE.  By definition, they don't specify http:// paths.

Comment: @bpeterson76 I had looked at it, and _relative_ links means for "relative folder hierarchy" not for same connection type.

Comment: and that is what the links are saying itself.